# Is there in D with GtkD an ObjectAttribute, e.g [UI] like in C#?

Tags: d, glade, gtkd

I had last used Mono (C#) with GTK, there is it possible to use `ObjectAttribute`s.
Is there in D with GtkD and Glade an `ObjectAttribute`, e.g `[UI]` like in C#?

For example like:

```
[UI] Gtk.Button button1;
[UI] Gtk.Label label1;
```

I did not understand the D documentation about Attributes.

Comment: Is it D attributes you're asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D has [UDA](http://dlang.org/attribute.html#UserDefinedAttribute)s (User Defined Attributes).

Example from documentation:

```d
@(3) int a;
@("string", 7) int b;

enum Foo;
@Foo int c;

struct Bar
{
    int x;
}

@Bar(3) int d;
```

Example of how they're used in [cerealed](https://github.com/atilaneves/cerealed):

```d
struct MyStruct {
    ubyte mybyte1;
    @NoCereal uint nocereal1; //won't be serialised
    @Bits!4 ubyte nibble;
    @Bits!1 ubyte bit;
    @Bits!3 ubyte bits3;
    ubyte mybyte2;
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any mentions of UDAs in GtkD.